# Delete keycode not returning in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Values of all the keys are returning except `delete` in the following code:

JavaScript Code

```
function charCnt(evt) {
            var inp = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
            alert(inp);
            return true;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="txt" onkeypress="return charCnt(event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Did you try it with another event, like onKeyDown? I believe there are some issues with onKeyPress and some keys in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Try with **keyup** or **keydown**:

```
function charCnt(evt) {
            var inp = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
            alert(inp);
            return true;
}

<textarea id="txt" onkeyup="return charCnt(event)"></textarea>
```